# centos yum update all 68 server

Tags: centos, redhat, yum

We have 68 Centos server diff version 4.X 5.X, we dont want internet for update errata patches. Alternative like redhat satellite server in centos which use to update all the server local.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could setup a local yum repository on one server and update your server with that. [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/creating_a_local_yum_repository_centos) is a doc which also describes how to include updates.

a more sophisticated way would be using [spacewalk](http://www.redhat.com/spacewalk/). it is the open source software on which red hat builds its satellite server.

Comment: thank for your quick reply i have that from DVD which i have install os on all 68 server, one of the server has local repo but what about new rpm errata update's

Comment: i've added a link to an how-to which describes what you are looking for.

Comment: Spacewalk will also give a a sampling of management and provisioning features as well.  It's a good baby step to something more elaborate like cobbler/puppet/func.